# Embed Dataframe in Discord

Tags: python, dataframe, discord

i have a dataframe and I want to embed it in discord. The result is:
[discordcap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gLrXW.png)

how can i give some format to this?

thanks!

````
@bot.command()
async def ranking(ctx):
    await ctx.send(perfiles())```
````

Comment: Do you mean to send the dataframe in tsv format (`df.to_csv(sep='\t')`)? Otherwise you could send it as a markdown table (`df.to_markdown()`)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.